Could I use "that" if I merely have one bike?
On https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/, it says

In a restrictive clause, use that.
In a nonrestrictive clause, use which.

It shows two examples.

My bike that has a broken seat is in the garage. From this sentence, you understand that the speaker has at least one other bike
My bike, which has a broken seat, is in the garage. Here, the broken seat is simply a description of the bike in the garage. There’s no implication that the speaker owns more than one bike.

I am Chinese and learned from my teacher that we can use "that" in restrictive clauses.
If I merely have one bike, could I say "My bike that has a broken seat is in the garage."?
Is "My bike, which has a broken seat, is in the garage." also seems to be awkward? Because it implies that I have more than one bike.

"My bike, which has a broken seat, is in the garage" is fine if you have one bike, and matches the rules you quote. Is there some reason you don't want to do what the website and your teacher tell you to do? I broadly agree with them (although in practice not everyone follows the rules precisely).

@StuartF "Is there some reason you don't want to do what the website". I am not sure, it seems that "which" implies that "I have more than one bike". But I am not sure.

The website says that 'my bike that has a broken seat' implies that you have another bike (the one that doesn't have a broken seat!).

I am not sure that the that clause means the person has another bike, necesssarily. It would depend on context. My bike - that has a broken seat by the way - is in the garage. I think it can be read like that.

The opposite of what you feel is true.
"My bike, which has a broken seat, is in the garage"  suggests that you don't have another bike.
If the non-restrictive clause bothers you, rephrase as two independent clauses

My bike is in the garage.  It has a broken seat.

But don't get too bothered by the choice of words.  The intonation is more important than the word "that/which", and the context is even more important.
